# Product of Conjugacy Classes in a Group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a *non-abelian* group, and consider $x,y$ in $G-Z(G)$. Let $C(x)=x^G$ and $C(y)=y^G$ denote the conjugacy classes of $x$ and $y$ respectively.

**Question:** What conditions on $x,y$ imply that the product $C(x)C(y)$ of conjugacy classes is again a conjugacy class in $G$?

---

$\bullet$ Both the  notation $C(x)=x^G$ for conjugacy class are used in literature.

$\bullet$ Here $C(x)C(y)=\{(g^{-1}xg)(h^{-1}yh)\colon g,h\in G\}=\{x^gy^h\colon g,h\in G\}$.

Comment: I have never seen $C(x)$ used for the conjugacy class of $x$. It normally means the cntrtalizer of $x$, and using it for the conjugacy class seems unnecessarily confusing. You could use ${\rm Cl}(x)$.

Comment: It is possible that it is an open question. See http://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~malle/download/classprod.pdf